# Name for the pattern where a "response" object or tuple is returned

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

When writing JavaScript/TypeScript, I sometimes implement a pattern where a function returns either a response object (as shown below) or a response "tuple" (just meaning array with two items), rather than the raw value. Something like this:

`example.js`

```
function getName() {
  if (userPressedOk) {
    return {status: "OK", name: getName()}
  else {
    return {status: "FAIL", name: ""}
  }
}
```

`example.ts`

```
function getName(): { status: string; jobName: string } {
  if (userPressedOk) {
    return {status: "OK", name: getName()}
  else {
    return {status: "FAIL", name: ""}
  }
}
```

This is a slightly contrived example, but that's the basic idea. I am trying to imitate I style I have seen in functional programming languages. **Does this pattern have a name?**

Comment: Taking a tuple/record and returning one is quite common in FP, since functions can only receive/return a single value per call, unless you encode them in continuation passing style. Therefore I don't think there is a general name for functions with this type.

Comment: "*a response "tuple" (just meaning array with two items)*" for the record, [a tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) can also hold three or more items. It's just a small(-ish) collection of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen them called [Result Objects](http://wiki.c2.com/?ResultObject).

In the functional languages that you say you are borrowing from, the respecitive type is often called `Result` or `Either` (although it usually provides an error message in the fail case, not a default value).

Comment: My first encounter with this style of data structure I heard it called a Result Set (or Resultset) but maybe that was just terminology borrowed from the database world grounded in set theory